# Security for Strings to insert into MySQL table and in HTML page using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, string, xss

Now I am using the following function to secure my strings :

```
  function secure($data)
  {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    $data = str_replace("'", '"', $data);
    $search = array(chr(0xC2).chr(0xA0),chr(0xC2).chr(0x90),
                              chr(0xC2).chr(0x9D),chr(0xC2).chr(0x81),
                              chr(0xC2).chr(0x8D),chr(0xC2).chr(0x8F),
                              chr(0xC2).chr(0xAD),chr(0xAD));
    $data = str_replace($search, "", $data);
    return $data;
  }
```

Will this function be enought to secure strings?

**Which methods will you use to secure your strings to insert into `MySQL` and to prevent bugs such as `XSS` in `HTML page`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By saying 'Secure my strings' I am assuming you mean for output?

For DB output (which includes varaibles used in SELECT queries), use *_escape_string functions or even better use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with PDO objects.

For html output you should use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) rather than [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Additionally if running shell commands from input use [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) and [escapeshellcmd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php)

Comment: Unfortunately htmlentities returns weird symbols instead of Russian Characters

Comment: You need to specify the encoding

Answer (score 3):

All you need is PDO! [Prepared statements and stored procedures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

If you want to remove javascript from your code

- take a look at [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).
- use regular expression: `$html = preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $html);`
- or use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php)

  ```
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($html); // load the HTML string we want to strip

  $script_tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('script'); // get all the script tags

  $length = $script_tags->length;

  for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $script_tags->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild($script_tags->item(0)); // for each tag, remove it from the DOM

  }

  $no_script_html_string = $doc->saveHTML(); // get the HTML string back
  ```

Comment: will it also secure strings to add them into html page without < > or javascript code?

Answer (score 2):

You're playing with two different technologies that both require separate sanitization methods.

MySQL requires protection from SQL-Injection, most commonly breaking out of quotes and putting non-numeric types in numeric fields. String-variables in this case can be secured by a number of things. Using [Prepared Statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) can definitely help; methods such as [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string), or [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) can sanitize individual string variables where a combination of [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/is_numeric) and [`intval()`](http://php.net/intval) can help with integers. It all depends on your input, if you want to sanitize on the per-variable level; a Prepared Statement will give you more leniency by doing it on the statement/variable level.

XSS, on the other hand, is another beast entirely. Methods such as [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities) and [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) can help when outputting data, but it also highly depends on the context in which the data is being outputted. If you're outputting data such as `<span><?=$variable;?></span>`, either of these functions will help. However, something like `<a href="<?=$variable;?>">` will not.

For more details regarding XSS prevention, start with OWASP's [XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to secure against SQL Injection is to use parameterized queries.
And against XSS you can use a really good library (PHP) called HTML Purifier http://htmlpurifier.org/
hope it helps

Answer (score -3):

The only method you have to know is : `addslashes` :)

Comment: That's __not__ true. ``addslashes()`` is known to be not secure at all ;-).

Comment: e.g. http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string

Comment: Your post was made on 2006 and if you continue to create tables in `default-character-set=GBK` i hope you love much prehistory than UTF.